# Why somewhere between linux kernel 3.14 and 4.9 PCI devices naming has changed?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

i have device with two xilinx PCI cards connected to PCIe and the device architecture is PowerPC. I can switch the kernel version by making symlink in the /boot directory.

On 3.14 kernel lspci produces:

```
0000:00:00.0 Class 0604: Device 1957:0070 (rev 21)
0000:01:00.0 Class 0200: Device 1234:0045 (rev 78)
0001:02:00.0 Class 0604: Device 1957:0070 (rev 21)
0001:03:00.0 Class 0200: Device 1234:0100 (rev 63)
```

And on 4.9 kernel lspci produces:

```
9000:00:00.0 Class 0604: Device 1957:0070 (rev 21)
9000:01:00.0 Class 0200: Device 1234:0045 (rev 78)
a000:02:00.0 Class 0604: Device 1957:0070 (rev 21)
a000:03:00.0 Class 0200: Device 1234:0100 (rev 63)
```

lspci output corresponds to /sys/bus/pci/devices/ directory content. My question is why somwehere between kernel 3.14 and 4.9 pci device naming has changed? For both kernels we have same hardware, dtb device tree and everything else common.

Comment: Something happened to either endianess or to PCI support for PowerPC. Try first to find closest two version working-non-working. Then run `git bisect` on it. Also, try to use v3.14.x and v4.9.x type of kernels from stable tree.

Comment: I would guess that this is the reason: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1560514 .  If you agree I will make that into an answer.

Comment: Please, test first that the mentioned patch fixes your issue. But on the first glance it does something to device numbering indeed.

Comment: 0andriy, yes, it changes the domain value - the first part of the PCI Id - from a value starting at zero for the first domain found and incrementing to predictable numbers based on the device tree.  By sibislaw "testing the patch", I presume you mean either applying it to a 3.14 kernel or reverting it in a 4.9 one?

Comment: By the way, that is commit 63a72284 in Linux 4.7.

Comment: Yes it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that there are other PCI devices on your system. If indeed so, do you see difference with other PCI devices in context of output of lspci between these two kernels ?

Rami Rosen

Answer (score 0):

Re-doing my comment as an answer, since their was no response to my comment.  The question is why the reported domain parts of the PCI Ids which were 0 and 1 with Linux 3.19 are 0x9000 and 0xa000 with Linux 4.9.  Commit 63a72284 in Linux 4.7 changes the values assigned to domains to be predictable values based on the device tree information instead of consecutive numbers starting at 0.  I think it is a safe assumption that this commit is the reason for the change.